# Pass a value of the factory to the associated one

Tags: factory-bot

In the [FactoryBot GETTING STARTED page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) there is the following snippet which explains how to create an association.

```
factory :post do
  # ...
  association :author, factory: :user, last_name: "Writely"
end
```

In my case, I need to pass a value of the factory to the associated one.

```
factory :post do
  category: ['a','b','c'].sample
  association :author, factory: :user, expertise: ??CATEGORY??
end
```

I have tried several things (mainly putting curly braces) but nothing seems to work: Trait not registered: category.

Is there a way to pass the category selected for the post to its author?

Thanks

Comment: If a post category is for example `'a'`, the author's expertise is also `'a'`?

Comment: That is what I need when the category is `a` author's expertise must be `a` when the category is `b` author's expertise must be `b`, when the category is `c` author's expertise must be `c`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `after(:build)` callback:

```
factory :post do
  category ['a','b','c'].sample
  association :author, factory: :user

  after(:build) do |post|
    post.author.expertise = post.category
  end
end
```

Comment: have you able to solve your issue with above solution?